# Implied volatility calculator is wrong

Tags: python, finance

I'm a computer scientist trying to learn more about quantitative finance. I have a program for calculating the value of a European call option in the Black-Scholes model and am trying to add a method to calculate implied volatility to it.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pdb
from scipy.stats import norm

class BlackScholes(object):
  '''Class wrapper for methods.'''

  def __init__(self, s, k, t, r, sigma):
    '''Initialize a model with the given parameters.
       @param s: initial stock price
       @param k: strike price
       @param t: time to maturity (in years)
       @param r: Constant, riskless short rate (1 equals 100%)
       @param sigma: Guess for volatility. (1 equals 100%)
    '''
    self.s = s
    self.k = k
    self.t = t
    self.r = r
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.d = self.factors()

  def euro_call(self):
    ''' Calculate the value of a European call option
        using Black-Scholes. No dividends.
        @return: The value for an option with the given parameters.'''
    return norm.cdf(self.d[0]) * self.s - (norm.cdf(self.d[1]) * self.k *
                                     np.exp(-self.r * self.t))

  def factors(self):
    '''
      Calculates the d1 and d2 factors used in a large
      number of Black Scholes equations.
    '''
    d1 = (1.0 / (self.sigma * np.sqrt(self.t)) * (math.log(self.s / self.k)
                    + (self.r + self.sigma ** 2 / 2) * self.t))
    d2 = (1.0 / (self.sigma * np.sqrt(self.t)) * (math.log(self.s / self.k)
                    + (self.r - self.sigma ** 2 / 2) * self.t))
    if math.isnan(d1):
      pdb.set_trace()
    assert(not math.isnan(d1))
    assert(not math.isnan(d2))
    return (d1, d2) 

  def imp_vol(self, C0):
    ''' Calculate the implied volatility of a call option,
        where sigma is interpretered as a best guess.
        Updates sigma as a side effect.
        @rtype: float
        @return: Implied volatility.'''
    for i in range(128):
      self.sigma -= (self.euro_call() - C0) / self.vega()
      assert(self.sigma != -float("inf"))
      assert(self.sigma != float("inf"))
      self.d = self.factors()
    print(C0,
      BlackScholes(self.s, self.k, self.t, self.r, self.sigma).euro_call())
    return self.sigma

  def vega(self):
    ''' Returns vega, which is the derivative of the
        option value with respect to the asset's volatility.
        It is the same for both calls and puts.
        @rtype: float
        @return: vega'''
    v = self.s * norm.pdf(self.d[0]) * np.sqrt(self.t)
    assert(not math.isnan(v))
    return v
```

Here are the two test cases I currently have:

```
print(BlackScholes(17.6639, 1.0, 1.0, .01, 2.0).imp_vol(16.85))
print(BlackScholes(17.6639, 1.0, .049, .01, 2.0).imp_vol(16.85))
```

the top one prints out 1.94 which is reasonably close to the value of 195.21% given by http://www.option-price.com/implied-volatility.php. The bottom one however (if you remove the assert statements) prints out 'nan' and the following warning message. With the assert statements, `self.vega()` returns zero in the imp_vol method and then `assert(self.sigma != -float("inf"))`.

```
so.py:51: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  self.sigma -= (self.euro_call() - C0) / self.vega()
so.py:37: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  + (self.r + self.sigma ** 2 / 2) * self.t))
so.py:39: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  + (self.r - self.sigma ** 2 / 2) * self.t))
```

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.8.

Comment: I rounded 17.6639 to 17.66 when I typed it in on that website, adding the remaining decimals makes it agree exactly.

Comment: The idea of infinite volatility in options pricing does not make any practical sense, so I'm 99% confident that my output is a bug, but I don't understand the Black-Scholes equation well enough to debug it.

Comment: So, blame floating point weirdness?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing doesn't make a lot on sense.  You are trying to back out the implied vol of a massively in the money, short dated option.  The vega on this option will be effectively 0 so the implied vol number you get will be meaningless.   It wouldn't surprise me at all is floating point rounding gave you infinite vol.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vega to estimate implied volatility, you are probably doing some variant of a newtons gradient search, which does not converge to a solution in all circumstamces, I program in R, or VBA so can only offer a solution for you to translate, the bi-section search method is simple robust and always converges, from the man who wrote the complete book of option pricing models here is Espen Haugs algorithm for a bisection search to find the implied volatility;

The Newton-Raphson method requires knowledge of the partial
derivative of the option pricing formula with respect to volatility
(vega) when searching for the implied volatility. For some options
(exotic and American options in particular), vega is not known ana-
lytically. The bisection method is an even simpler method to estimate
implied volatility when vega is unknown. The bisection method
requires two initial volatility estimates (seed values):

1. A "low" estimate of the implied volatility, al, corresponding to
   an option value, CL
2. A "high" volatility estimate, aH, corresponding to an option
   value, CH
   The option market price, Cm, lies between CL and cH. The bisec-
   tion estimate is given as the linear interpolation between the two
   estimates:
   Replace al with 0 i+1 if c(cr, + ) < c m , or else replace aH with a i+ 1 if
   C(7,+ ) > c m until lcm — c(cri+i)i < E, at which point cr, ±1 is the implied
   volatility and E is the desired degree of accuracy.
   Computer algorithm
   This function returns the implied volatility of a European plain
   vanilla call or put option. With small modifications, the function can
   also be used to find the implied volatility for American and exotic
   options. The variable counter keeps track of how many loops have
   been done. If the implied volatility is not found to the specified accu-racy E within 100 loops, the algorithm stops and returns "NA" (not
   available).

````
      Function  GBlackScholesImpVolBisection(CallPutFlag 
       As String, S As Double,
       X As Double, T As Double, r As Double, _
       b As Double, cm As Double) As Variant
       Dim vLow As Double, vHigh As Double, vi As Double
       Dim cLow As Double, cHigh As Double, epsilon As 
   Double
   Dim counter As Integer
   vLow = 0.005
   vHigh = 4
   epsilon = le-08
   cLow = GBlackScholes ( CallPutFlag , S, X, T, r, b, vLow)
   cHigh = GBlackScholes ( CallPutFlag , S, X, T, r, b, vHigh)
   counter = 0
   vi = vLow + (cm — cLow ) * (vHigh — vLow) / ( cHigh — cLow)
   While Abs(cm — GBlackScholes ( CallPutFlag , S, X, T, r, b, vi )) > epsilon
   counter = counter + 1
   If counter = 100 Then
   GBlackScholesImpVolBisection
   Exit Function
   End If
   If GBlackScholes ( CallPutFlag , S, X, T, r, b, vi ) < cm Then
   vLow = vi
   Else
   vHigh = vi
   End If
   cLow = GBlackScholes ( CallPutFlag , S, X, T, r, b, vLow)
   cHigh = GBlackScholes ( CallPutFlag , S, X, T, r, b, vHigh )
   vi = vLow + (cm — cLow ) * (vHigh — vLow) / ( cHigh — cLow)
   Wend
   GBlackScholesImpVolBisection = vi
   End Function```
````